# PayPal Permissions API

Tags: paypal

I am trying to set up permissions so that when clients want to use my PayPal integration service, I take them through the process of giving my software permission to make express checkout payments on their behalf.

So far, I have followed these steps (I am using the PayPal permissions SDK for .Net):

1. Use requestPermissions to add the "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT" permission to
   return the access token.
2. Use getAccessToken (passing the token and verification code) to obtain the token secret
3. I then store the token and token secret for future payments.
4. I attempt to test a payment using the sandbox environment using the ProfileFactory.createPermissionAPIProfile() and generating the signature using "com.paypal.sdk.core.OauthSignature.getAuthHeader".  One thing I am not completely sure of here is what is passed as the API URL, I am passing "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/"

Now, when I do this and call "SetExpressCheckout", I get an error message saying I don't have permission.

So, I wanted to debug this to test what permissions I have, so I call GetPermissions passing the token but the response object is null?  This is really odd, I would expect an error if there was a problem, I cannot see any reason why a null value is returned?

Anyone can help point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We use the NVP API and to carry out API calls on behalf of a third party, you must send the 3rd party's PayPal ID in the Subject of the API request. The SOAP API has the same element.

The API doc says this is the authorizing_account_emailaddress, though we send the PayPal ID and that works.