# Paypal API calls on behalf of a third party

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-permissions

I can't find how to make API call with PayPal SDK on behalf of a third party . I found this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/ and this [PayPal Permissions API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316305/paypal-permissions-api), but I did'n see any methods in Paypal permissions-sdk-php or rest-api-sdk-php to do that. Does anybody know how make API call with user access token?

Comment: I need to send money from a user to another user using PayPal API permissions.

Comment: Are you going to use Express Checkout?  If so, you can simply set the PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter to the email address or account ID of the receiver and you don't even have to mess with permissions.  Just use your own API credentials.

Comment: No, I need to send money from first user to second user in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually asking the same question. But I finally found the answer by looking at sample code on the JAVA SDK [here](https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-java/blob/master/permissionssample/src/main/java/com/sample/permissions/GetBasicPersonalDataServlet.java).

Since I am using PHP on my code I need to simply convert it like below:

```
use PayPal\Auth\IPPThirdPartyAuthorization;
use PayPal\Auth\PPSignatureCredential;
use PayPal\Auth\PPTokenAuthorization;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
$attributeList = new PersonalAttributeList();
$attributeList->attribute = array(
    'http://axschema.org/namePerson/first',
    'http://axschema.org/namePerson/last',
    'http://axschema.org/contact/email',
    'http://axschema.org/contact/fullname',
    'http://openid.net/schema/company/name',
    'http://axschema.org/contact/country/home',
    'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/auth/schema/payerID'
);

$request = new GetBasicPersonalDataRequest( $attributeList );
$request->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope;

$apiCredential = null;
if ( ! empty( $data['token'] ) && ! empty( $data['tokenSecret'] ) ) {
    $thirdPartyAuth = new PPTokenAuthorization( $data['token'], $data['tokenSecret'] );
    $apiCredential = new PPSignatureCredential( 'jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com', 
        'WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F', 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu' );

    $apiCredential->setApplicationId( 'APP-80W284485P519543T' );
    $apiCredential->setThirdPartyAuthorization( $thirdPartyAuth );
}

$service = new PermissionsService( $config );
try {

    /*
     *  ## Making API call
    Invoke the appropriate method corresponding to API in service
    wrapper object
    */
    if ( $apiCredential != null )
        $response = $service->GetBasicPersonalData( $request, $apiCredential );
    else 
        $response = $service->GetBasicPersonalData( $request );

    return $response;
} catch (Exception $ex) {}
```

I hope this helps everyone having the same issue.

**EDIT 1:**

Thanks @Alex for pointing this out. For the classes under namespace `PayPal\Auth` please include PayPal SDK Core that you can get [here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-php). If you use composer to use the PayPal Adaptive SDK then those classes should be included automatically.

Comment: Several of the classes you are using here do not exist in the `Paypal\Auth` directory using the REST API.

Comment: @AlexMcCabe thanks, I've updated the answer. Pls check :D

Comment: that makes more sense, however how do you directly integrate this with the REST API to take payments on behalf of a third party. It's just so confusing.

Comment: Forgot to say that this is not the REST API. This is for the PayPal classic API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/. OP originally asked particularly the permissions service. The REST API has different approach.